# RegisterCollection from previously registered types with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

Using Simple Injector, I'm trying to register an `IEnumerable` of non generic `ICommandHandler`. This will be a collection of objects that decorate all instances of my generic `ICommandHandler`s. The essential code is provided below. My `CommandService` is the type that depends on the `IEnumerable` of `ICommandHandler`.

How do I register this in my composition root?

```
public interface ICommandHandler
{
    Type CommandType { get; }
    void Handle(object command);
}

public interface ICommandHandler<in TCommand>
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    void Handle(TCommand command);
}

public class WeaklyTypedCommandHandler<TCommand> : ICommandHandler,
    ICommandHandler<TCommand>
    where TCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _commandHandler;

    public WeaklyTypedCommandHandler(ICommandHandler<TCommand> commandHandler) {
        _commandHandler = commandHandler;
    }

    public Type CommandType { get { return typeof (TCommand); } }

    public void Handle(object command) {
        _commandHandler.Handle((TCommand)command);
    }

    public void Handle(TCommand command) {
        _commandHandler.Handle(command);
    }
}
```

My `CommandService`:

```
public class CommandService : ICommandService
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<ICommandHandler> _commandHandlers; 
    private readonly ISerializationFormatter _formatter;

    public CommandService(IEnumerable<ICommandHandler> commandHandlers,
        ISerializationFormatter formatter)
    {
        _commandHandlers = commandHandlers;
        _formatter = formatter;
    }

    public void Execute(string command)
    {
        if (command == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

        var request = _formatter.Deserialize<CommandRequest>(command);

        var handler = _commandHandlers
            .Single(x => x.CommandType == request.Command.GetType());

        handler.Handle(request.Command);
    }
}

private void ConfigureContainer(Container container)
{
    container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),new[] { typeof(BusinessLayer).Assembly });

    container.RegisterDecorator(typeof(ICommandHandler<>),
        typeof(WeaklyTypedCommandHandler<>));

    //container.RegisterCollection<ICommandHandler>????
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should seriously consider removing the non-generic `ICommandHandler` interface, because its only reason for existence is to be able to do the dispatching, but there are better -more elegant- ways of doing this. What you are doing only complicates your design -and registration- tremendously.

Instead, rewrite your `CommandService` to the following:

```
public class CommandService : ICommandService {
    private readonly Container _container; 
    private readonly ISerializationFormatter _formatter;

    public CommandService(Container container, ISerializationFormatter formatter) {
        _container = container;
        _formatter = formatter;
    }

    public void Execute(string command) {
        if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

        var request = _formatter.Deserialize<CommandRequest>(command);
        Type handlerType = typeof(ICommandHandler<>)
            .MakeGenericType(request.Command.GetType());           
        dynamic handler = _container.GetInstance(handlerType);
        handler.Handle((dynamic)(request.Command));
    }
}
```

You would typically not want to have classes to have a dependency on the DI library, but this class only contains infrastructure logic, so you can move it inside the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Since the Composition Root already takes a really strong dependency on your DI library, [it is fine](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/) to have classes as part of the Composition Root that take a dependency on the container as well.

Without the non-generic `ICommandHandler` interface, your registration will be childs play:

```
container.Register(typeof(ICommandHandler<>), new[] { typeof(BusinessLayer).Assembly });

container.Register<ICommandService, CommandService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Last note, ditch the `in` keyword of the `ICommandHandler<in TCommand>` interface. Comands and their handlers have a one-to-one mapping; you will never have a derived command and its base command that use the same command handler implementation. Using the `in` keyword only communicates the wrong message to other developers. Yes I know that Resharper tells you to do so, but you shouldn't blindly follow your tools. Resharper knows shit about your design ;-). Ditch the `in`!

But if you hate using `dynamic` and reflection, I would suggest the following model:

```
public sealed class CommandService : ICommandService {
    private readonly Container _container; 
    private readonly ISerializationFormatter _formatter;

    public CommandService(Container container, ISerializationFormatter formatter) {
        _container = container;
        _formatter = formatter;
    }

    public void Execute(string command) {
        if (command == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("command");

        var request = _formatter.Deserialize<CommandRequest>(command);
        Type handlerType = typeof(WeaklyTypedCommandHandler<>)
            .MakeGenericType(request.Command.GetType());           
        var handler = (ICommandHandler)_container.GetInstance(handlerType);
        handler.Handle(request.Command);
    }

    private interface ICommandHandler {
        void Handle(object command);
    }

    public class WeaklyTypedCommandHandler<TCommand> : ICommandHandler {
        private readonly ICommandHandler<TCommand> _commandHandler;

        public WeaklyTypedCommandHandler(ICommandHandler<TCommand> commandHandler) {
            _commandHandler = commandHandler;
        }

        public void Handle(object command) {
            _commandHandler.Handle((TCommand)command);
        }
    }
}
```

This model mixes both worlds, as it:

- Uses the container to get a `WeaklyTypedCommandHandler`.
- This handler implements `ICommandHandler` (but not `ICommandHandler<T>`), so you can do two simple casts and don't need reflection.
- Both the `WeaklyTypedCommandHandler` and non-generic `ICommandHandler` are implementation details of the `CommandService` class.
- Compared to `dynamic`, this model will keep working, even if your command handler implementations (or decorators) are (accidentally) defined as internal.
- Just like `dynamic`, but compared to using the reflection API (using `Type.GetMethod().Invoke()`), thrown exceptions from within command handlers will not get wrapped in `TargetInvocationException`s.

Downside of this model is that you need an extra class and interface, although the amount of extra code is minimal.

Comment: I was afraid you were going to say that.  Your solution was the original design (but I think you already knew that :)).  The overall goal of keeping the DI container out of the service was so I could include the service in the core assembly that is shared across multiple business layers and not have to take a dependency on the DI Library.  Would you suggest I just define a CommandService inside every host?

Comment: I would suggest you extract your composition root to a separate class library and only expose a factory to create your container, that way you can parameterize any configurations you need for a host.

Comment: I'm currently working on a project where we're using this approach, we're using `AppSettings` to define the configuration of each of our ports (e.g. Storage (InMemory|EntityFrameWork), Session (InMemory|Mvc), EmailInfrastructure (Fake|SmtpClient|SendGrid) to list a few).

Comment: Whether or not to duplicate code or create a reusuable composition root depends on the amount of code that needs reuse. Don't forget you ccan always inject a `Func<Type, object>` instead of Container if you decide to define this class outside your CR and hand-wire this class.

Comment: @Steven Thanks Steven for an in depth answer.  I think I will go with your first response.  The reflection and dynamic don't bother me, but might bother some of my more junior colleagues.  They'll just have to learn.  I'm not ready to wire up a Func<Type, object>.  This would basically expose a service locator to the rest of my system.  I don't think I have enough hosts/composition roots (yet) to warrant this.

Comment: @BrettJaner: Note that you don't have to wire up a `Func<Type, object>` into the container. You can as easily make the registration as follows: `container.RegisterSingleton<ICommandService>(new CommandService(container.GetInstance))`. I agree, don't make the following registration: `container.RegisterSingleton<Func<Type, object>>(container.GetInstance)`. That will easily lead to the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Comment: @Steven ahh yes! I like this :)